# Spring mvc 3.1 with hibernate 4.3 validation and errors

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, validation

I had the following setup:

IndexCntl.java (Controller):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, ModelMap map) {
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        map.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
        map.addAttribute("email", new Email());
        Map sexoOpts = new HashMap();
        sexoOpts.put("M", "Homem");
        sexoOpts.put("F", "Mulher");

        map.addAttribute("sexoList", sexoOpts);
        return "index";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/save-email", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doSaveEmail(@Valid @ModelAttribute("email") Email email, Model model, BindingResult result){
        log.info("Email debug: "+email.getEmail()+" "+email.getMysexy()+" "+email.getWantedsexy());

        if (result.hasErrors()){
            log.info("Entrou result.hasError()");
            return "index";
        }
        Date date = new Date();
        email.setCreationDate(date);
        try{
            emailBo.saveEmail(email);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        model.addAttribute("email", new Email());
        return "index";
    }
```

index.jsp (view):

```
<form:form action="save-email" method="POST" modelAttribute="email" cssStyle="display:-webkit-box">
                <form:select path="mysexy" cssStyle="width:120px;">
                    <form:option value="" label="- Sou -"/>
                    <form:options items="${sexoList}" />
                </form:select>
                <form:errors path="mysexy" cssClass="errors"/>
                <form:select path="wantedsexy" cssStyle="width:120px;">
                    <form:option value="" label="- Busco -"/>
                    <form:options items="${sexoList}" />
                </form:select>
                <form:errors path="wantedsexy" cssClass="errors"/>
                <br/>
                <form:errors path="wantedsexy" cssClass="errors"/>
                <div class="input-append">
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="30" maxlength="30" placeholder="E-mail" class=""/>
                    <form:errors path="email" cssClass="errors"/>
                    <input id="btncadastrar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" value="Cadastrar E-mail"/>
                </div>
            </form:form>
```

and part of the model Email.java:

```
@Document
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Email extends BaseBean {

    // @Pattern(regexp =
    // "^[\\w\\-]+(\\.[\\w\\-]+)*@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$",
    // message="E-mail com formato incorreto.")
    @NotNull(message = "Não pode ser vazio")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Não pode ser vazio-nulo")
    @org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email(message = "E-mail inválido")
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Informe ao menos um valor")
    private String mysexy;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Informe ao menos um valor")
    private String wantedsexy;
```

and i'm receiving this error when i try to pass with a empty email in input:

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'email' on field 'email': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.email.email,NotEmpty.email,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [email.email,email]; arguments []; default message [email]]; default message [Não pode ser vazio-nulo]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'email' on field 'email': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.email.email,NotEmpty.email,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [email.email,email]; arguments []; default message [email]]; default message [Não pode ser vazio-nulo]
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:110)
```

what can be wrong in my setup???

Comment: if i create the method initBinder in the controller and annote it with "@InitBinder" and then i set a binder.setValidator it start to work, but i will have to implement it in hand? there is no sense to use hibernate validator then...

Answer (score 1):

You explicit forbid empty values:

```
    @NotNull(message = "Não pode ser vazio")
--> @NotEmpty(message = "Não pode ser vazio-nulo") 
    @org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email(message = "E-mail inválido")
    private String email;
```

Hibernate validate the entity before saving or update, and your entity fails.

You can disable this validation in you `persistence.xml` file configuration.

```
<persistence ...>
  <persistence-unit ...>
    ...
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If you want to check only some validation rules, then you can use "Validation Groupes"

- @See [Hibernate Reference, Chapter 22.1. Bean Validation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e9763)
- @See JSR 303 Bean Validation

---

If your problem is that the controller method is not invoked, then it is because of the `@Valid` annotation for `Email`. If you want to have a controller method to be invoked event if a parameter with `@Valid` annotaton is not valid, then you need a parameter of type `BindingResult` DIRECTLY AFTER that parameter

```
public String doSaveEmail(@Valid @ModelAttribute("email") Email email, BindingResult resultForEmail, Model model, BindingResult resultForModel)
```

Comment: i'm not using the hibernate persistence, just validation implementation of it. the problem appear when i try to hit a controller with a @Valid, when i submit the method "doSaveEmail" of the controller the code don't join it because of the validation he gives me this exception that starts with "BindException" and "BeanPropertyBindingResult", i'm doing something wrong using spring mvc 3.1 with hibernate-validator 4.3???